# Powershell Match a string that may contain asterix

Tags: powershell

I'm running into issues with a string that gets parsed a certificate friendly name and attemps a lookup to see if it already exists. When the friendly name contains a '*' the script bombs.

I know I could escape the '*', but I don't have control of when it's parsed to the script. What is the best way of either escaping on the fly or matching strings when/if they contain metacharacters?

```
# this does not work
# Bad argument to operator '-match': parsing "*.test.com" - Quantifier {x,y} following nothing..
if(Get-ChildItem cert:\ -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.FriendlyName -and $_.FriendlyName -match '*.test.com'} | Select-Object -First 1) { 
  exit 1 
} else { 
  exit 0 
}

# this works fine
if(Get-ChildItem cert:\ -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.FriendlyName -and $_.FriendlyName -match 'string.test.com'} | Select-Object -First 1) { 
  exit 1 
} else { 
  exit 0 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your specific case, I think you want to test for an exact match.  In that case you should use the `-eq` operator instead of `-match`.

mjolinor's answer provides a good general explanation on whild cards.

Comment: Thankyou - yes correct I am not trying to wildcard match, string match is what I am after.

Answer (score 0):

'*.test.com' is a wildcard pattern.  Use that with the -like operator.  The -match operator uses a regular expression for matching, which has different rules and metacharacters than the wildcard match.

See:

```
Get-Help about_Wildcards
Get-Help about_Regular_Expressions
```